# Why is the data on my JTable only visible after I selected it?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jtable

I have a JTable with some data coming from a String but when I run my program the JTable appear to be empty untill I select the rows. Then, it shows everything. How come this is happening?

After running program:

[image]

After I select the data in the table:

[image]

The code surrounding my JTable is:

```
public class PanelConsulta1 extends JPanel {

private String[] nombresColumnas = {"Ciudad de Residencia", "Salario Promedio"};
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTable tabla;
private controlador control;

public PanelConsulta1(){
    control = new controlador();
   
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLayout(null);
    tabla = new JTable(inicializarTabla());
    
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.add(tabla);
    scrollPane.setSize(400, 400);
    tabla.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    tabla.setSize(400, 400);
    add(scrollPane);
    setVisible(true);
    
}

private DefaultTableModel inicializarTabla(){
    ArrayList<Consulta1Vo> lista = null;
    Object[][] ayudante = null;
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(nombresColumnas, 0);
    try {
        lista = control.consultarRequerimiento1();
        ayudante = new Object[lista.size()][2];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        ayudante[i][0] = lista.get(i).getCiudadResidencia();
        ayudante[i][1] = Math.round(lista.get(i).getSalarioPromedio());
        String ciudad = lista.get(i).getCiudadResidencia();
        double promedio = Math.round(lista.get(i).getSalarioPromedio());
        Object[] datos = {ciudad, promedio};
        //modelo.addRow(datos);
    }
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel(ayudante, nombresColumnas);
    return  modelo;
}
```

}

---

Comment: Don't do `scrollPane.add(tabla);`, do `scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);` instead

Comment: You might want to look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer That worked! Thanks for the tip! Will definitely give it a read!

Comment: I am not sure if it is related but did you try using `repaint()` ?

Comment: 1) `setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) One good example of why the programmer should not try to guess that right size (let alone position) of components can be seen `scrollPane.setSize(400, 400); .. tabla.setSize(400, 400);` ..

Comment: .. no matter what set of number are provided, the scroll pane is too small the the table - given the scroll pane should include a scroll bar. Do not try to guess how large components should be or their location within the GUI. ***Use. Layouts.*** Ultimately, despite that the advice of @MadProgrammer seems to have fixed this problem, for you, expect pain in future. Fix it by giving up on `null` layouts.